# Can't install Android Studio on Windows7 with an error

Tags: android-studio

I tried to install `Android Studio 2.1` on my netbook, 32 bit.
But, after I execute `android-studio-bundle-143.2915827-windows.exe`, an error occurred and I cannot install it.

```
the following SDK components were not installed android support repository and android sdk tools
```

I searched it but I have no idea what to do, would you please help me?

[image]

I click "retry", but this error occurs again, then I click "cancel" and uninstall and reinstalled it, this error happens again.

Comment: Are you using a proxy?

Comment: @Juan Cruz Soler Thank you for your comment. I don't use any Proxy. I use this site, http://www.ugtop.com/spill.shtml. And it says "none".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I just needed to run .exe as an administrator.